# Android Speech Recognition App

Tags: android

I want to make an app that will take a the command from the user and show it in the Edittext (or any other container). I'm using google speech recognition but it shows me a bunch of sentences that the Engine Heard.. I want to get the right one from all those option without showing the list into the Edittext..

And if possible I'll like to do that in continuous sentence (like, Hi Friend. please come for the meeting, you are late). Please help me out with this.

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code can be wired up to a "Speak" button and will receive a single string, which is the best match to whatever was said.

To start the speech recognition activity:

```
private static final int VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

private void startVoiceRecognitionActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_WEB_SEARCH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,"Speak Now");
    startActivityForResult(intent, VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

To receive the result:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        if (matches != null && matches.size() > 0) {
            String spokenText = matches.get(0);
        }
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: Can you help me with this.. What is wrong with my code. When i run it on device it crashes. I think the problem is in this code..


protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  if(requestCode == request_code && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
  {
   ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
   String option = null;
   if(matches != null && matches.size() > 0)
   {
    option = matches.get(0);
   }
   et.setText(option);
  }
  
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
 }

Comment: If it's crashing you need to look in LogCat to see what the exception is, to identify the cause of the crash.

Comment: Sir I'm running it on Phone. And I don't know how to see LogCat in that.

Comment: Plug the phone into the computer with USB and look in Eclipse or DDMS, or install the "CatLog" app on the phone. To do Android development, you need to know how to use LogCat!

Comment: Thank you sir.. I have fixed the problem.. I was setting the string in EditText which was the error.. When i switched to TextView the programs runs fine..